# Should I go to an average university for summer research

Tags: research-process, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

I am an U.S. undergraduate in math and computer science at a university that is very good (top 5 in some rankings) in electrical engineering and computer science. I am planning to apply for PhD at next school year, and I'm wondering if I should go to another university for summer research.

Currently, I'm working with a professor on mathematical programming at the electrical/computer engineering department toward publishing a paper. Although I am mostly doing the numerical sides, I think what I'm doing does require some training. I have taken 3 optimization courses (including graduate ones), and I have gained some familiarity with this area.

Now I wonder, as for the summer, is there any advantage for me to participate in another university's summer research program, in the case that this university is not very good? In contrast to working with my current advisor or with another professor.

I don't care about how much I get paid. What matters to me is how it will affect my PhD application. I know people doing summer REU at a university and got accepted to PhD programs before applying. So for me, I don't see the reason of applying to REU at places other than the top universities such as MIT, Berkeley, Stanford, etc. My advisor and other professors in my school also have connections to these top universities, so their recommendation letters should carry more weight as well.

My question applies to students at top universities in any research area.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not very good'. Is it an R1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should definitely be worth it if you have a specific PhD theme in mind. Research in the US is very decentralized, so an 'average' university might have a research group (or a number of them) that are widely recognized as experts in a particular domain. So, if you know what kind of research you want to pursue in your PhD, a REU with a specific PI would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I see. Thank you. So in this case I should be looking for the professor specifically? But how would I know how recognized they are, especially if they are young? My advisor does not have a high h-index but has connections with MIT and Berkeley due to his Post-doc, Ph.D, and his collaborators.

Comment: Your advisor should know other groups working in your field. Depending on what you want to do next,  he can point you to the appropriate people. Also, h-indexes and school reputation only get you so far, you'll see that in research it's a more informal sort of recognition that is much more important.